# C# .NET: Get Start-up/Designer-assigned values of Controls

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to retrieve the designer-assigned values of controls, e.g. when I designed a `TextBox` with the `.Text` "Hello World", then change the `.Text` during runtime: How can I retrieve the String "Hello World" again during runtime?

My thoughts so far:
I can write a set-up routine and assign these "default" values in there alone, and call that method again when ever I want to reset the values.
Cons:
- Not as flexible (No way of resetting individual Controls)
- would need to write a routine for each implementation
- missing out on the convenience of just setting the values once in the designer

I would really like a static method/extension which would enable me to plug in my Control and get the values assigned to it within my class designer.

I started trying to implement an extension within my extension library, where I create a new instance of the main Form Class and grab the value from there - but that approach has obvious disadvantages:
- The Form Class may have different constructor signatures, like `string[] args` for applications with console arguments; creating instances of unknown signatures isn't trivial or a good idea in general
- It's a heavy weight approach; depending on the complexity of the project, you might not want to create piles of instances every time you want to get a Control's designer-assigned value.
- This would execute what ever code is in the constructor

So I'm really hoping I can use `Reflection` or something similar to get to the designer-assigned values.
But I have no idea how to go about looking for that; googling things like "visual .net get designer default control value" yielded no relevant results.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

My test extension method currently looks something like this:

```
    public static string getDefaultText(this Control c)
    {
        Form mainForm = Form.ActiveForm; // just a quick easy way to test this
        Type t = mainForm.GetType();
        var f = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        Control a = ((Form)f).Controls[c.Name]; // unfortunately, .Controls only contains direct children, not all descendants; recursive searching would be needed
        return a.Text;
    }
```

and works for what it is, which is to say a proof of concept of a bad approach :/

Comment: use resources ... `System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(YourForm)); resources.ApplyResources(control, "ControlName");`

Comment: but first you have to set "Localizable=True" in designer

Comment: Interesting approach, @Selvin! That work-around does give me access to the Control versions laid out in the Designer. Not ideal for resetting a single attribute (My work-around creates a proxy instance from which to apply the desired attribute.  
Do you know how to read out single attributes?

Answer (score 0):

[@Selvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin) commented with a good idea: Let me formulate a preliminary work-around from it.

Once the Form uses *Localization* (Set `Localizable` to `True` at design-time), a version of the Control that represents its state in the Designer is stored in the app's *Resources*.
This seems to include all designable properties (everything in the *Properties* panel/window) (**Edit: apparently not**).

Using a [ComponentResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.componentresourcemanager?view=netframework-4.8) (implementing [ResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=netframework-4.8)), we can apply that state to a Control again during runtime using its method [ApplyResources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.componentresourcemanager.applyresources?view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_ComponentResourceManager_ApplyResources_System_Object_System_String_):

```
    public static void resetControl<T>(this T c, string key = "") where T : Control // Using generic approach for the convenience of being able to use the Type T
    {
        Form f = c.FindForm();
        ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(f.GetType()); // Manage the resources from our Form class
        if (key == "")
        {
            resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name); // Simply natively apply all resources
        }
        else // If we want to reset only one specific property...
        {
            // rather than trying to get to the data serialized away somewhere, I'm using this work-around
            T r = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(c.GetType()); // create a new instance of the Control in question
            resources.ApplyResources(r, c.Name);
            setAttr(c, key, r.getAttr(key)); // setAttr and getAttr are helper extensions I always have on hand as well
        }
    }

    public static void setAttr(this object o, string key, object val)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in o.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            string nam = prop.Name;
            if (nam == key)
            {
                prop.SetValue(o, val);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    public static dynamic getAttr(this object o, string key)
    {
        Type myType = o.GetType();
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.Name == key)
            {
                return prop.GetValue(o, null).ChangeType(prop.PropertyType);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Usage:

```
    // Reset everything to the Designer state:
    textBox1.resetControl();

    // Reset only the TextAlign property:
    textBox1.resetControl("TextAlign");

    // Reset only the Dock property:
    textBox1.resetControl("Dock");
    // ... etc
```

This works reasonably well and I can write further abstractions making the process of resetting certain values easier.
I don't like having to create a new instance of a control, but I'm willing to live with it for this work-around. However, better approaches are definitely welcome.

### Update: Shortcomings

- It looks like an empty `.Text` from Designer will not overwrite a non-blank `.Text` using `ApplyResources`, it seems.

  - However, using a proxy Control instance like in the case of supplying "Text" as a key string in my extension method above, this still works
- It looks like it doesn't work with most Controls. Testing so far only had it work on TextBoxes, Labels and CheckBoxes with the .Text property, but **not** the .Checked property of the CheckBox
- Attempting to reset a NumericUpDown's .Text (for example because you're carpet-bombing everything with resetting "Text" in order to reset it for those who have a relevant .Text) will set its .Value to 0

Comment: Uh... Caveat: An empty `.Text` from Designer will not overwrite a non-blank `.Text`, it seems